# Eclipse: How to save custom files to Workspace .metadata folder?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to save settings from a plugin in the `.metadata/.plugins/com.example.myplugin` folder. When I use the preferences, they are saved there, but I want to save custom files there. Now, the Eclipse documentation says I should never write files there using file operations but only with platform commands.

So, how do I save custom workspace metadata the correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That location is the plug-in's 'state location' you get it using:

```java
Bundle bundle = ... your plug-in's bundle

IPath stateLoc = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

It is entirely up to your plug-in to manage this folder. You do use ordinary Java file I/O in this folder.

One way to get your `Bundle` is:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```